# SQL finding duplicates

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table with following columns with over million rows,

ID,Name

1,Ram

2,Meer

3,Ram

4,Raj

I need to create column dups, if 2 IDs have same name then assign Yes. IF not assign NO

ID, Name, Dups

1,Ram,Yes

2,Meer,No

3,Ram, Yes

4,Raj,No

Comment: [Select Distinct](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS558US558&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=select%20distinct)

Comment: Are you using SAS or SQL?

Comment: I think SAS can use pure SQL procs.

Comment: It can. But if this question is about SAS, then sorting and using first will be very direct. If this is SQL, it's a bit less direct (at least imo). Note the edit history though... actually not clear what software is being used here

Answer (score 4):

You should sort your data by Name. Then use the first command, a la

```
PROC SORT DATA = mydata;
BY name id;
RUN;

DATA mydata_mod;
SET mydata;
BY name;
IF first.name and last.name THEN duplicate = "No";
ELSE duplicate = "Yes";
RUN;
```

Basically what we're doing here is saying, "hey, is this name both the first and last occurrence of that name in my data set? If so, it's not a duplicate. If not, then it is.

Also note that you could modify your data step a bit to get unique names that have duplicates:

```
DATA mydata_mod (KEEP = name);
SET mydata;
BY name;
IF first.name and last.name THEN duplicate = "No";
ELSE duplicate = "Yes";
IF first.name and duplicate = "Yes";
RUN;
```

I've used logic like the later DATA step a few times, so I wanted to go ahead and mention it, in case it helps :-)

Comment: I don't think that's quite right.  I believe you need to change it to `if first.name and last.name then duplicate = "No"` ....  This way the first of the duplicates will also be flagged correctly.

Comment: Note that you could also do something like if first.name AND last.name THEN duplicate = "No"; ELSE duplicate = "Yes";  That would be better suited if you want to flag every record that has a duplicate (essentially, "which records have duplicate names?", not "which records might be considered superfluous?"). Also, you could apply a keep statement in your data step and an if statement to only keep distinct names for which there are duplicates. But that all kind of depends on what you actually need.

Comment: Good point Robert, and I agree. Looking at the sample data, I would do if first.name and last.name THEN duplicate = "No."  When I read it the first time, I interpreted  it as "show me which records are superfluous." But I agree that the way you suggested is right. I'm making the edit now.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a count of all the duplicates. 0 would mean no and > 0 would mean yes.

```
Select name, count(*) cnt from my_table
group by name;
```

If you just want Yes and No, replace count(*) with: Case when count(*) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another SQL Solution:

```
data have;
input ID Name $;
datalines;

1 Ram
2 Meer
3 Ram
4 Raj
;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select a.ID, a.name, case when count(name)>1 then "YES"
                        when count(name)=1 then "NO"
                        else "CHECK"
                    end as DUP
    from have as a
    group by name
    order by ID;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as another column:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT null FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.Name = t.Name AND t2.ID <> t.ID)
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS Dups
FROM MyTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.id,
       t.name, 
       (case  when A.countval >1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Dups
from
(
select name, COUNT(*) as countval
from t
group by name
)A
inner join t
on A.name = t.name
```